# Asymmetry of random graphs

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, permutations, random-graphs

By a well known result of Pólya we know that the number $g_n$ of isomorphism classes of simple graphs on $n$ vertices is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{2^{\binom{n}{2}}}{n!}$. In [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X08006900?np=y) the author claims that from Pólya's theorem it follows that almost all graphs are asymmetric (i.e. have only one automorphism).

How does that follow? I see that by Burnside's lemma $\frac{n!}{2^{\binom{n}{2}}} g_n$ equals the excepted value of the number of automorphisms of a random graph on $n$ vertices, and from the asymptotic equivalence we can conclude that this excepted value is bounded from above. But doesn't that only mean that a random graph will not have “too many” automorphisms? How does it follow that a random graph is asymmetric if $n$ is sufficiently large?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I changed the title. If you wanted something else, please feel free to re-edit.

Comment: @Vishesh Thank you! This one fits well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tilde{G}$ be a random graph chosen uniformly at random among all graphs on $n$ vertices (i.e. $\tilde{G}=G(n,p=1/2)$). Let $P_k$ be the probability that $\tilde{G}$ has exactly $k$ isomorphisms. Note that $P_1+\ldots +P_{n!/2}+P_{n!}=1$ and $2^{{n \choose 2}}P_{\ell}/\ell$ is the number of isomorphism classes with size $\ell$. So
\begin{align*}
g_n = \sum_\ell \frac{2^{{n \choose 2}}P_\ell}{\ell} \geq 2^{{n \choose 2}}\frac{(1-P_{n!})}{n!/2}+\frac{2^{{n \choose 2}}P_{n!}}{n!}=\frac{2^{{n \choose 2}}}{n!} \left(2-P_{n!}\right).
\end{align*}

If $P_{n!} \neq 1+o(1)$, then this lower bound on $g_n$ would be larger than $(1+o(1))\frac{2^{{n \choose 2}}}{n!}$ (infinitely often), contradicting Polya's result.

EDIT: I should be a little clearer. $P_k$ is the probability that $\tilde{G}$ has isomorphisms to exactly $k$ graphs on $n$ vertices.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but unfortunately I do not see why the equation $P_{n!} = 1 + o(1)$ would imply the claim. Furthermore, there are only two graphs on $n$ vertices admitting $n!$ automorphisms, hence we already know $P_{n!} = \frac{2}{2^\binom{n}{2}}$ - even without Pólya's theorem.

Comment: @Dune The isomorphism class corresponding to having all possible $n!$ automorphisms would correspond to $P_1,$ not $P_{n!}$. Graphs in the event corresponding to $P_{n!}$ have only the trivial automorphism. In other words, $P_{n!}$ is the probability that the graph is asymmetric.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your definition of $P_k$. But nevertheless I do not get the conclusion, yet. What is the contradiction if we assume $P_{n!}$ would be small, e.g. $P_{n!} = 0$?

Comment: @Dune That's alright. If $P_{n!}$ does not tend to 1, then there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $P_{n!} \leq 1 -\epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$. For these such $n$, we would have that $g_n \geq \frac{2^{{n \choose 2}}}{n!} (1+\epsilon)$ contradicting the result that $g_n = (1+o(1)) \frac{2^{{n \choose 2}}}{n!}$.

Comment: I see, I made a stupid mistake in reasoning... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you google on "almost all graphs are asymmetric" you will find a lot of information. At the top is http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/11-12/constraint/summerschool/nesetril.pdf, which offers a nice proof of the claim.

The proofs that I am familiar with do not usually start from Polya's lemma, since proving that will of of the same order of difficulty as proving the claim from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am aware of other proofs (I googled the same :) ) but I really want to understand the claim mentioned above. I would prefer a proof using Pólya's lemma since it is great tool which also applies in many other situations.